# How insert page break in rtf files using asp.net with c#.net version 1.1?

Tags: c#, asp.net, rtf, .net-1.1, page-break

How insert page break in rtf files using asp.net with c#.net version 1.1?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look here: http://latex2rtf.sourceforge.net/RTF-Spec-1.0.txt

For RTF v1.0 the control character was `\sbkpage`.

EDIT:

Its the same for v1.5 too: http://www.biblioscape.com/rtf15_spec.htm

Answer (score 0):

You can add \page.

Here's a tutorial at http://www.webdev-tuts.com/generate-rtf-file-using-php.html

in php.

Comment: Unfortunately, that link is now dead